# Scraping <li> item using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'd like to scrape https://www.deutsche-biographie.de/ . Specifically, I'm interested in scraping the following information about each individual

- Name
- Year of birth
- Year of death
- Profession
- Place of birth ('geburt' in source code) and coordinates
- Place of death ('tod' in source code) and coordinates
- Places of activity ('wirk' in source code) and coordinates

With the code below, I scraped name, year of birth, year of death, and profession.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

page = read_html(x = "https://www.deutsche-biographie.de/search?_csrf=45b6ee54-385e-4777-90bf-9067923e6a00&name=meier")
name = page %>% html_nodes(".media-heading a") %>% html_text()
information = page %>% html_nodes("#secondColumn p") %>% html_text()
result = data.frame(name, information, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#manipulate data in columns
result$yearofbirth = sub("(^[^-]+)-.*", "\\1", result$information) #extract characters before dash
result$yearofdeath = sub(',.*$','', result$information)
result$yearofdeath = sub('.*-','', result$yearofdeath) #extract characters after dash
result$profession = sub("^.*?,", "", result$information) #extract characters after comma
result$profession = trimws(result$profession, whitespace = "[ \t\r\n]") #trim leading and trailing white space
result$information = NULL
```

However, I'm struggling with scraping the place of birth/death/activity from the <li element.
The source code looks as follows, with data-orte standing for the places of birth/death/activity (geburt/tod/wirk) and data-name standing for the name of the individual.

```
 <li class="media treffer-liste-elem" id="treffer-sfz55763" data-orte="Rendsburg@54.3012661,9.6596678@geburt;Rendsburg@54.3012661,9.6596678@wirk;Kiel@54.3216753,10.1371858@wirk;Magdeburg@52.1315889,11.6399609@wirk;Rostock@54.14736345,12.109015599915@wirk;Frankfurt/Oder@52.3438922,14.5544166@wirk;Gottorf@54.5117924,9.54054973309832@wirk;Padua@45.407059,11.8767269@wirk;Bologna@44.4936714,11.3430347@wirk;Basel@47.5429886,7.5969912@wirk;Königsberg@54.7066424,20.5105165@wirk;Danzig@54.3482114,18.6542829@wirk;Prag@50.087656,14.4212126@wirk;Amsterdam@52.3710089,4.9001115@wirk;Frankfurt@50.1432793,8.6805975@wirk;Rostock@54.14736345,12.109015599915@wirk;Magdeburg@52.1315889,11.6399609@tod" data-name="Maier, Michael">
```

I would be very grateful for any hint on how to scrape the places!
Best, Natalie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option to achieve your desired result may look like so:

1. First step is similar to the solution proposed by @Kafe: Get the information on places from the `data-orte` attribute and split by `;` to get a list of places
2. As a second step I make use of `lapply` to put the places of birth, death and activity in separate columns of your `result` dataframe
3. In the third step I make heavy use of `tidyr::extract` which makes it easy to extract multiple pieces of information from a string and put them into separate columns in one step.

Note: I also used a different approach to extract the years of birth and death.

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

page = read_html(x = "https://www.deutsche-biographie.de/search?_csrf=45b6ee54-385e-4777-90bf-9067923e6a00&name=meier")
name = page %>% html_nodes(".media-heading a") %>% html_text()
information = page %>% html_nodes("div.media-body p") %>% html_text()
result = data.frame(name, information)
result$information <- result$information %>% trimws() %>% strsplit(split = ", \\n") %>% lapply(trimws)
result <- tidyr::unnest_wider(result, information) %>%
  rename(years = 2, profession = 3) %>% 
  tidyr::extract(years, into = c("year_of_birth", "year_of_death"), regex = "^.*?(\\d{4}).*?\\-\\s(\\d{4})")

places <- page %>% html_nodes("li.treffer-liste-elem") %>% html_attr("data-orte") %>% strsplit(";")

result$place_of_birth <- lapply(places, function(x) x[grepl("@geburt$", x)]) %>% unlist()
result$place_of_death <- lapply(places, function(x) x[grepl("@tod$", x)]) %>% unlist()
result$place_of_activity <- lapply(places, function(x) x[grepl("@wirk$", x)])

result <- result %>% 
  tidyr::extract(place_of_birth, into = c("place_of_birth", "place_of_birth_coord"), regex = "^(.*?)@(.*?)@.*$") %>% 
  tidyr::extract(place_of_death, into = c("place_of_death", "place_of_death_coord"), regex = "^(.*?)@(.*?)@.*$")

result
#> # A tibble: 10 × 9
#>    name   year_of_birth year_of_death profession place_of_birth place_of_birth_…
#>    <chr>  <chr>         <chr>         <chr>      <chr>          <chr>           
#>  1 Meier… 1718          1777          Philosoph  Ammendorf bei… 51.4265204,11.9…
#>  2 Meyer… 1772          1849          Jurist; B… Frankfurt/Main 50.1432793,8.68…
#>  3 Meier… 1809          1898          Bremer Ka… Bremen         53.0758099,8.80…
#>  4 Major… 1502          1574          lutherisc… Nürnberg       49.4538501,11.0…
#>  5 Meyer… 1810          1874          schweizer… Sursee Kanton… 47.1774826,8.10…
#>  6 Maier… 1568          1622          Alchemist… Rendsburg      54.3012661,9.65…
#>  7 Meier… 1692          1745          Jurist; A… Bayreuth       49.9427202,11.5…
#>  8 Mejer… 1818          1893          Jurist; P… Zellerfeld (H… 51.804126,10.33…
#>  9 Meyer… 1474          1548          Bürgermei… Basel          47.5429886,7.59…
#> 10 Hirsc… 1770          1851          Mathemati… Friesack (Mit… 52.7395263,12.5…
#> # … with 3 more variables: place_of_death <chr>, place_of_death_coord <chr>,
#> #   place_of_activity <list>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response and explanations! Also, your RegEx approach for extracting year_of_birth and year_of_death looks much cleaner than mine! Do you perhaps have any suggestion on how to access all the names from the input field on the top of https://www.deutsche-biographie.de/ without having to type manually a name in the input field?

Comment: Hm. I have had a look at the page. First. If you have a look at the url there is a piece `&name=meier`. Hence, you could replace "Meier" by another name e.g. `Schmidt` to get the results for that name. Still, the tricky part is to get all search results as only up to 10 results will be displayed on a page. Moreover you still need a list of all names. To this end I would suggest to scrape the names of all persons in the database as a first step, e.g. from `https://www.deutsche-biographie.de/name/ndb/A`you could get a list of all persons in NDB with a name starting with an "A".

Comment: ... As a second step you could loop over the list of name to extract the results.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Stefan! I also thought about scraping the names and looping over each name afterward, but imagine it a bit time-consuming, as there are a lot of people having the same or a similar (similar search results are shown as well) name. That means a lot of entries would be scraped multiple times. I'll open a new stackoverflow post about it since it's not really related to the original question here. If I don't get closer to the solution there, I will do it as you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution helps:

```
page %>% 
  html_elements("#secondColumn > ul") %>% 
  html_children() %>% html_attr("data-orte") %>% 
  str_split(";")
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution.